# Why datagridview rows are shifted when import database C#

Tags: database, datagridview, rows, fill, tableadapter

I have a dataGridView which displays a database from an Access file used tableadapter.

My problem is:

rows sequence in access file order from 1 to 60 (picture 1) (this is what I need)

rows sequence in tableadapter order form 56-60  / 1-55  the tableadapter move to first line after 55 in fill operation (picture 2)

rows sequence in dataGridView display like tableadapter (picture 3)
why why this shift in rows?

[image]

Comment: Finally i find the solution i use this
dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
to order rows sorted

Answer (score 0):

Databases can return data in any order when queried. If you want a specific order you have declare it. Generally, you should never rely on anything that processes a list of data returning it in a particular order, unless the data container has a way of guaranteeing the order. As you've found, by setting the sort order of the datagridview, your data shows in the order you expect